# Why would TextOut() be using a different coordinate system than AlphaBlend()?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I'm trying to write a text overlay function that generates a semitransparent background with text on it in the top right hand corner of the viewport.  I wrote a test MFC application project with mostly default settings (I don't remember exactly, but AFAIK, none of the settings should cause the problems I'm seeing).

Here is the code:

```
void DrawSemitransparentRect(CDC& destDC, CRect rect, float percentGrayBackground, COLORREF overlayColour, float overlayPercentOpaque)
{
    rect.NormalizeRect();
    CDC temp_dc; // Temp dc for semitransparent text background
    temp_dc.CreateCompatibleDC(&destDC);

    CBitmap layer; // Layer for semitransparent text background
    layer.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&destDC, 1, 1);
    CBitmap* pOldBitmap = temp_dc.SelectObject(&layer);

    BLENDFUNCTION blendFunction = { AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 0, 0 };

    auto DrawSemitransparentRectHelper = [&](COLORREF colour, float transparency)
    {
        temp_dc.SetPixel(0, 0, colour);
        blendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha = BYTE(transparency * 255 / 100);
        // Draw semitransparent background
        VERIFY(destDC.AlphaBlend(rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height()
            , &temp_dc, 0, 0, 1, 1, blendFunction));
    };

    // Lighten up the area to make more opaque without changing overlay colour.
    DrawSemitransparentRectHelper(RGB(255, 255, 255), percentGrayBackground);
    // Draw overlay colour
    DrawSemitransparentRectHelper(overlayColour, overlayPercentOpaque);

    temp_dc.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
}

void DrawOverlayText(CDC & dc, CFont &windowFont, CRect const& windowRectDP, CString const& overlayText, CRect* pBoundingRectDP)
{
    static bool debug = true;

    int savedDC = dc.SaveDC();
    ::SetMapMode(dc.GetSafeHdc(), MM_TWIPS);

    // Reset the window and viewport origins to (0, 0).
    CPoint windowOrg, viewportOrg;
    ::SetWindowOrgEx(dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, &windowOrg);
    ::SetViewportOrgEx(dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, &viewportOrg);

    LOGFONT logFont;// = { 12 * 10, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, _T("Times New Roman") };
    windowFont.GetLogFont(&logFont);
    logFont.lfHeight = 12 * 10; // 12 point font?  Why isn't this *20?  TWIPS are 20ths of a point.

    // Font for the overlay text
    CFont font;
    font.CreatePointFontIndirect(&logFont, &dc);
    CFont* pOldFont = dc.SelectObject(&font);

    // window rect in Logical Points
    CRect windowRect(windowRectDP);
    dc.DPtoLP(windowRect);

    // Get text extent in Logical Points
    CRect textRect;
    dc.DrawText(overlayText, textRect, DT_CALCRECT);

    // inflation rectangle to add pixels around text
    CRect inflate(8, 0, 8, 4);
    dc.DPtoLP(&inflate);

    // Create the bounding rect on the right hand of the view, making it a few pixels wider.
    CRect boundingRect(textRect);
    if (!debug)
    {
        boundingRect.InflateRect(inflate);
    }
    boundingRect.NormalizeRect();
    boundingRect += CPoint(windowRect.Width() - boundingRect.Width(), 0);


    CRect boundingRectDP(boundingRect);
    if (pBoundingRectDP || !debug)
    {
        // Get the bounding rect in device coordinates
        dc.LPtoDP(boundingRectDP);
        *pBoundingRectDP = boundingRectDP;
    }

    if (!debug)
    {
        // round the bottom corners of the text box by clipping it
        CRgn clip;
        boundingRectDP.NormalizeRect();
        clip.CreateRoundRectRgn(
            boundingRectDP.left + 1 // +1 needed to make rounding coner match more closely to bottom right coner
            , boundingRectDP.top - boundingRectDP.Height() // Getting rid of top rounded corners
            , boundingRectDP.right
            , boundingRectDP.bottom + 1
            , 16, 16 // rounding corner may have to be more dynamic for different DPI screens
        );
        ::SelectClipRgn(dc.GetSafeHdc(), (HRGN)clip.GetSafeHandle());
        clip.DeleteObject();
    }


    // Calculatte centre position of text
    CPoint centrePos(
        boundingRect.left + (boundingRect.Width() - textRect.Width()) / 2 + 1
        , boundingRect.top + (boundingRect.Height() - textRect.Height()) / 2 + 1);

    if (debug)
    {
        // in debug mode, output text and then put semitransparent bounding rect over it.
        dc.SetBkMode(debug ? OPAQUE : TRANSPARENT);
        dc.SetBkColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
        dc.SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
        dc.TextOut(centrePos.x, centrePos.y, overlayText);

        DrawSemitransparentRect(dc, boundingRect, 60, RGB(0, .25 * 255, .75 * 255), 40);
    }
    else
    {
        // 2 pixel offset in Logical Points
        CPoint textShadowOffset(2, 2);
        dc.DPtoLP(&textShadowOffset);

        // in !debug mode, output semitransparent bounding rect and then put text over it.
        DrawSemitransparentRect(dc, boundingRect, 60, RGB(0, .25 * 255, .75 * 255), 40);

        dc.SetBkMode(debug ? OPAQUE : TRANSPARENT);
        dc.SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
        dc.TextOut(centrePos.x, centrePos.y, overlayText);
        dc.SetTextColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));
        dc.TextOut(centrePos.x - textShadowOffset.x, centrePos.y - textShadowOffset.y, overlayText);
    }
    // Restore DC's state
    dc.SelectObject(pOldFont);
    dc.RestoreDC(savedDC);
}

// OnPaint() function for CView derived class.
void COverlayOnCViewView::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    
    CString m_overlayText = _T("abcdefg ABCDEFG");

    CFont windowFont;
    LOGFONT logFont = { -12, 0, 0, 0, 400, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, 0, 0, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, 0, _T("Segoe UI") };
    windowFont.CreatePointFontIndirect(&logFont, &dc);

    CRect windowRect;
    GetClientRect(windowRect);

    DrawOverlayText(dc, windowFont, windowRect, m_overlayText, nullptr);
}
```

Now, this works perfectly well in the default project, where I get the following:

[image]

But when I put it into another preexisting project, I get this:

[image]

You can see that the text is actually positioned above the translucent rectangle.

If I move the rectangle down the height of the text box, by changing

```
boundingRect += CPoint(windowRect.Width() - boundingRect.Width(), 0);
```

to

```
boundingRect += CPoint(windowRect.Width() - boundingRect.Width(), textRect.Height());
```

I get:

[image]

It's like the text function is specifying the bottom left corner rather than the top left corner for placement.

I wrote the free functions so that it should work with any DC, even if that DC has had its coordinate system manipulated, but perhaps I've forgotten to reset something?

The default project is using MFC 14.0.24212.0, but the project I tried to import this code into is using MFC 12.0.21005.1.  Could that be an issue?  I'm not sure how to change the default project to use the earlier version of MFC to test that.

## Edit

Note that in the default project, I could have put the code into the `OnDraw()` function like this:

```
void COverlayOnCViewView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    COverlayOnCViewDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    // TODO: add draw code for native data here
    CString m_overlayText = _T("abcdefg ABCDEFG");

    CFont windowFont;
    LOGFONT logFont = { -12, 0, 0, 0, 400, 0, 0, 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, 0, 0, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, 0, _T("Segoe UI") };
    windowFont.CreatePointFontIndirect(&logFont, pDC);

    CRect windowRect;
    GetClientRect(windowRect);

    DrawOverlayText(*pDC, windowFont, windowRect, m_overlayText, nullptr);
}
```

The only reason why I didn't was because the application I'm putting this into doesn't have one and I wanted to mimic that project as closely as possible.  If you create a default application to test this, remember either to put the `ON_WM_PAINT()` macro in the `MESSAGE MAP` or use the `OnDraw()` function shown instead.  They both seem to have the same results in the default project.

Comment: Rough guess is not accounting for SetTextAlign().

Comment: Exellent @HansPassant.  That was the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Your `AlphaBlend` is using a bitmap from `CreateCompatibleBitmap` whose width and height is 1. Does this actually do anything? Why do you call `AlphaBlend` twice? To draw centered text you can use `dc.DrawText(rect, text, DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE)`, although I don't think you should even need that.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, yes, `AlphaBlend()` will stretch the bitmap to the space that I want it to go.  Since it is only one colour, I only need a pixel of that colour.  I called `AlphaBlend()` twice so that I can mute the existing background further, without intensifying the colour.  Yes, I could have used `DrawText()`.  I was having some issues with it before, but that may not be a problem now.  It doesn't really matter at this point.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know `AlphaBlend` can use single pixel and stretch it.